# Error : Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format

Tags: android, fonts, android-gradle-plugin

I has problem when build app via Gradle as below. And I got the error:
Error:(516) Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(298) Original attribute defined here.
Error:(516) Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(298) Original attribute defined here.

But I don't find places using "font" attr in my modules.

Please help me on that.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.3-alpha', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('com.weiwangcn.betterspinner:library-material:1.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext', module: 'library'
    }
    compile('com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:2.6.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
        compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.9@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-core:2.6.1@aar'
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:2.6.1@aar'
    compile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:2.6.1@aar'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0'
    compile 'ayar.oktay.library:advancedtextview:0.4.5'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.kyleduo.switchbutton:library:1.4.4'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.1@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.6.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0-native'
    compile 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.1.9'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'


    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
    debugAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.2.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case the problem was in a library that defined attribute `"app:font"`.
I removed that library and all the places in xml where were written `"app:font"` and my problem disappeared.

As an additional example:
If you have got the error `AAPT: Attribute "iconTint" already defined with incompatible format` then you should search and delete `"app:iconTint"` in your xml to resolve this problem.

Comment: Thanks #Dima Kozhevin. I re-order the library dependency, after that this is fixed as well.

Comment: What if I need to use the library and also "app:font" in my app (actually it's been used at many places in the code)? What is the alternative then?

Comment: @amar I think you should ask developers of that library change the name of the parameter.

Comment: @Nguyễn Văn Lai  I have same issue with fontfamily please advise me how you re arrange the library dependency. Thanks in advanced