# Android Sdk 26 compile error

Tags: android, onesignal

I am using [onesignal](https://onesignal.com) for android notification and onesignal need sdk v26 and when i try to compile v26.1.+ following errors are displayed.

```
Error:(140) Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(128) Original attribute defined here.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'D:\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\26.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

The first error is for :

```
<declare-styleable name="FontFamilyFont"><attr name="fontStyle"><enum name="normal" value="0"/><enum name="italic" value="1"/></attr><attr format="reference" name="font"/><attr format="integer" name="fontWeight"/></declare-styleable>
```

Second:

```
<declare-styleable name="CfViewsCustomAttributes"><attr format="integer" name="font"><enum name="normal" value="0"/></attr></declare-styleable>
```

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.2'
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.2, 3.99.99]'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you learn me more ?

Comment: The problem is not in the OneSignal library.
You need to find a library(or libraries) that uses app:fontStyle and app:font.

Comment: @DimaKozhevin Where use app:font?

Comment: @DimaKozhevin Do you have any example of this libraries?

Comment: @DimaKozhevin hey man ???

Comment: No, I haven't got an example.
Try to use a command in the Android Studio command "Find in path ..." and looking for values "app:font" and "app:fontStyle".

Comment: @DimaKozhevin Sorry man. I got this.i was using a custom library for fonts i remove it and ok...

Comment: I'm glad to see that) I noticed my comment with a helpful answer was deleted. I leave it here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46279656/3166697