# Gradle : android support version conflict

Tags: android, gradle, android-8.0-oreo

I'm having the following conflict while compiling against android sdk 26

`AAPT: Attribute "iconTint" already defined with incompatible format.`

So I set the support version to `26.0.2` and tried to force all my dependencies to ignore their support version with the following : 
    `exclude group: 'com.android.support'`

However, the `com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement` dependency still refers to its own support dependency, even though I exclude it :

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:"
compile ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.0"){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

`./gradlew app:dependencies`

```
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.0
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 26.0.2 (*)
```

Any idea why all my dependencies exclude their support by applying the above rule, and why play-services-basement doesn't ? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error : Attribute "font" already defined with incompatible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988998/error-attribute-font-already-defined-with-incompatible-format)

Comment: no, unfortunately, it's not duplicated on that.

Comment: it is the same because you should search and delete "app:iconTint" in your xml to resolve this problem.

Comment: indeed, the issue came from one of my dependecies (material-tap-target-prompt) that had the same attribute. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("test")) {
                details.useVersion '26.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```