# AAPT: Attribute "layout_anchorGravity" already defined with incompatible format. AND 25.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, msbuild

I have a cordova app project in Visual studio 2017 that has been building fine up until now. No changes had been made to the project.

Now we are getting this build errors:

```
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : C:\Users\Adam.Akers\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BCA\HH\BcaView\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:173: AAPT: Attribute "layout_anchorGravity" already defined with incompatible format.    
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : C:\Users\Adam.Akers\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\BCA\HH\BcaView\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml:172: AAPT: Original attribute defined here.    
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.    
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * What went wrong:    
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.    
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25\build-tools\25.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : * Try:    
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.    
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
```

Any help would be great. I have removed plugins and check the version of the SDK and we have changed nothing

Comment: try changing build tools version

Comment: I've tried this (I think). But where should this be done in Visual studio?

Comment: i have no idea about visual studio, Did you change your targetSDKversion?

Comment: Yes, to 25 and no change.

Comment: FIXED - to fix this I had to create a new blank cordova project in VS2017, copied the www file from the old project and gradually add in each plugin used within the project one at a time to find the fault. then update that pulgin accordingly.

Comment: @AdamAkers, Since you have fixed this issue, you can convert your comment to the answer, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 1):

> AAPT: Attribute “layout_anchorGravity” already defined with incompatible format. AND 25.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

According to the error info "*AAPT: Attribute "layout_anchorGravity" already defined with incompatible format.*", it seems you have defined a custom attribute named `layout_anchorGravity` in your application code that conflicts in some manner with the [android-namespaced font attribute introduced in Android O](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/working-with-fonts.html). Try renaming or removing that custom attribute, like:

```
<declare-styleable name="AATextView">
    <attr name="layout_anchorGravity" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

To

```
<declare-styleable name="AATextView">
    <attr name="typeface" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Certified: [Error : Attribute “font” already defined with incompatible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45988998/error-attribute-font-already-defined-with-incompatible-format)

Hope this helps.