# Issues in android source code , How can i fix it?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]Im Working my project in android Studio 3.1 Canary 4 . Suddenly Im getting this issue "Error:(252, 5) Attribute "type" already defined with incompatible format.". How Can I recover this Problem.

Here I attached my Logcat,
[image]

Now Im chaning SDK version 27 but same issue occur.
App Gradle,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.casperon.app.rydepass"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 17
    versionName "4.2"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
aaptOptions {
    cruncherEnabled = false
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
 }

  dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile project(':slideDateTimePicker')
  compile project(':CountryCodePicker')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
compile 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:expandableheightlistview:1.0.0'
compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.0'
compile 'com.baoyz.swipemenulistview:library:1.3.0'
compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.7.0'
compile 'com.github.jakob-grabner:Circle-Progress-View:v1.2.2'
compile 'me.drakeet.materialdialog:library:1.2.2'
compile 'com.wang.avi:library:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.0-rc1'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0-rc1'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.0-rc1'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.0-rc1'
compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.5.0'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.8.3'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.github.crazy1235:RichEditText:v2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

}

Countrycodepicker gradle:
[image]

Slidedatepicker gradle,
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to `Clean` and `Re-build` project.

Comment: Yes but its not resolved. @HeisenBrg

Comment: So, you are using `Canary` version Android Studio. Simply, it's a preview version it may have some issues.

Comment: you (or one of the libraries) uses appcompat libs v27, while your targetSDK is 24. This could be the problem. Try usinng SDK 27 too

Comment: But I tried to import this code in Android 2.3. Same issue occur

Comment: Can you please post the `gradle` here??

Comment: Now I Changed sdk 27 , but same problem occur.

Comment: do you have any custom attributes defined in your project?

Comment: Please update the libraries as mentioned by @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: yes @VladyslavMatviienko . Now i attached

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani i update my library but can't find any solution.

Comment: 1) don't add images of code. Add code as text always. 2) that are not attributes, that are styles.

Comment: Tried removing `aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled`??

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani same issue

Comment: Please post all `gradle` files used in your project.

Comment: I posted, kindly check it @MohammedsalimShivani

Comment: You might like https://stackoverflow.com/q/45988998/3166697

Comment: @anafroz Sorry for late response. Your `gradle`s are haing different SDK levels. Please make them use the same version.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarity.

You are using different versions of the same library, so change the following from:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

To:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

Also, if some of the other libraries use different versions, this will cause the same problem.

---

Another thing, `compile` is redundant, you should use `implementation`

So, it should actually be:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
```

Comment: Tried didn't get solution.

Comment: In my answer I said -`Also, if some of the other libraries use different versions, this will cause the same problem.` So you will have to go and look what library is using a different version.

Comment: I changed implementation but this is not working for me

Answer (score -2):

```
1. compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
2. compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
```

add both dependencies it may help.